# Having issue running SSIS script task in Visual Studio with 2019 as target version

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, visual-studio-2019, script-task

We are upgrading from Sqlserver 2012 to 2019 in that process we need to migrate our SSIS packages also from 2012 to 2019. We have lot of script task which uses connection string and other configurations from DtsDebugHost.exe.config It was loaded from Binn folder of Sql server installation folder by default in sql server 2012. but in sqlserver 2019 we couldn't figure out from where it is loaded to the appdata local folder. So our script task is failing because it couldn't acquire connection and couldn't resolve the libraries ( which are used in our config).

Comment: I think your question would be improved if you could provide some concrete details about a specific example of what works in 2012 and how it fails in 2019. Package A uses this script Task. The config it uses has this structure (anonymize values as needed). We run the packages on a machine that is Windows 10/11 Windows Server 20XX. We run the packages through SQL Agent, the command line, Visual Studio, our custom app which uses the following code to launch the package...

Answer (score 0):

For someone who's interested in this question, the file is at somewhere like this C:\Users\yourUsername\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\150\SSIS\ApplocalConfigs